# select full record based on unique id mongodb

Tags: mongodb, distinct, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which has a unique `_id` field but duplicate values in the `transactionreceipt` field. I want to filter it out by unique `transactionreceipt` and I want full document data of that record.. is this possible?

I read like only indexes can be fetched from using distinct.. is there anything where I can get full  document also.?

My dataset is:

```json
{"_id": {"$oid": "580af4ce1b407e114sdvsdbf"},
    "transactionreceipt":"734416173864583200",
    "type":"recharge"
},
{"_id": {"$oid": "580af4ce1b407f495sagfdgaed"},
    "transactionreceipt":"734416173864583200",
    "type":"recharge"
},
{"_id": {"$oid": "580af4ce1b407safasfe114bf"},
    "transactionreceipt":"734585659418738700",
    "type":"recharge"
},
{"_id": {"$oid": "580af4ce1b407f4956436sdg"},
    "transactionreceipt":"734585659418738702",
    "type":"recharge"
},
{"_id": {"$oid": "580af4ce1b407f495safasgvd"},
    "transactionreceipt":"734723784694562800",
    "type":"recharge"
},
{"_id": {"$oid": "580af4ce1b407f495325ds"},
    "transactionreceipt":"734723784694562808",
    "type":"recharge"
}
```

And the query would be like

```
 var tx = db.usertransactions.distinct( "transactionreceipt",{"type" : "recharge"} ) 
tx.forEach(statistics=>{
        printjson(parseFloat(statistics));// i want all details to be displayed here
        } 
 )
```

I can get only `transactionreceipt` here, nothing else. Where am I going wrong? Is there any aggregate function which could do this?

Answer (score 0):

What about trying following way-

```
var tx = db.usertransactions.aggregate(
[
    { $match: { type: "recharge" } },
    { 
        $group: {             
            _id : { id: { $id: "$oid" }, transactionreceipt: { $transacreceipt: "$transactionreceipt" }}
        } 
    },

]) tx.forEach(statistics=>{
        printjson(parseFloat(statistics));
    })
```

You can check for more details - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/